# Oracle Text Context-Index returns all rows for contains() query with wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, full-text-search

We use Oracle Text in a Oracle Database (11.2.0.4.0) to perform full-text search over stored documents, as well as over multiple columns in our database.

For these multi-column indexes we noticed that some  double-sided wildcard queries return the wrong number of results: The whole table!

Our application translates the query of a user into a double-sided wildcard query (e.g. "york" -> "%york%") and passes them to the `contains` operator.
We re-ran this on the database and could reproduce it.

Consider, for example, a table containing cities where the full-text index spans all columns: Zip-Code, Cityname, State and Country:
`select * from city where contains(cityname, '%york%')>0`

The following query arguments seem to return a wrong number of results (all rows):

- %s%
- %i%
- %d%
- %c%

What I checked already:

- Interestingly, the non-working queries are all format-arguments in C. But I have not been able to find these as keywords or special operators in the Oracle Text documentation.
- I checked that the stop word list does not contain these queries.
- I set a custom lexer and turned on the "mixed case" option for it, which seems to fix the issue for lowercase queries, but the issue persists for upper case queries (%S%).

The `score` operator returns a value of 6 for the rows that should not match:

```
select cityname, state, zip, score(1) from city where contains(cityname, '%s%', 1)>0
```

```
---------------------------------
|Cityname  |State|Zip | Score(1)|
|-------------------------------|
|La Cibourg|NE   |2332| 6       | - WRONG
|Morlon    |FR   |1638| 6       | - WRONG
|Leuk Stadt|VS   |3953| 12      | - Correct row
---------------------------------
```

Do you know any (mis-)configuration that can cause this?

**Update**
The exact version is 11.2.0.4.0, with Patch 18842982 applied.
The script to create the table and index is below:

```
drop table city_copy;

create table city_copy (
 city_nr number not null,
 zip_code varchar2(60),
 city_name varchar2(60),
 state varchar2(60)
 );

 insert into city_copy
 select 1, 2332, 'La Ciboug', 'NE' from dual
 union all
 select 2, 1638, 'Morlon', 'FR' from dual
 union all
 select 3, 3953, 'Leuk Stadt', 'VS' from dual;

 commit;

 exec   ctxsys.ctx_ddl.drop_preference('CITY_MULTI');
 exec   ctxsys.ctx_ddl.create_preference('CITY_MULTI', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
 exec   ctxsys.ctx_ddl.set_attribute('CITY_MULTI', 'COLUMNS', 'ZIP_CODE, CITY_NAME, STATE');

 create index city_idx_ft on city_copy(zip_code)
 indextype is ctxsys.context parameters ('datastore CITY_MULTI sync (on commit)');
```

The current settings for the default lexer are:

```
DEFAULT_LEXER   COMPOSITE           GERMAN
DEFAULT_LEXER   MIXED_CASE          YES
DEFAULT_LEXER   ALTERNATE_SPELLING  GERMAN
```

Our stoplist is unchanged from the [default stoplist for German](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/astopsup.htm#CCREF2302)

Comment: Can you add over here the create table, the insert of the three rows you just showed, and the full SQL you used to create the index? 
Please also provide the full DBMS version, and patches if any were applied...
Oracle text has it issues, and has it bugs, and for providing a relevant answer - I want  to be able to simulate the behavior you seeing.

Comment: @evenro Added! I fixed the description of the query I ran slightly to make it clearer (instead of '%york%' the '%s%' query)

Comment: This is not an answer yet, but I remember that if you lookup for less (or equal) to 3 chars 
(with a %) usually there is an issue with Oracle Text. Let me research it a bit.. I am not sure if it is a bug or expected ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO, after quite a bit research...

I am still not sure if it is a bug, but although my intuition said it is the lexer that causes this behavior - it is not.

Please add to the preference an attribute named DELIMITER with a value of NEWLINE

```
exec ctx_ddl.set_attribute('CITY_MULTI', 'DELIMITER', 'NEWLINE');
```

That would solve your issue.

The default delimiter is COLUMN_NAME_TAG which probably conflicts with too short parameters (it is supposed to treat your data as if it is an XML, and probably somewhere in how Oracle concatenate the text there are the single characters you were looking for).

It looks to me like for the multi column data store Oracle Text constructs for each row you have an XML that contains the name of the column in it, something like:

```
<XML>
   <zip_code>2332</zip_code>
   <city_name>La Ciboug</city_name>
   <state>NE</state>
</XML>
```

and that XML is being indexed (or a structure that is similar to it).

and when looking for just S the s from the word "state" returns in every row.

The new line changes the way the text is being built to

```
2332
La Ciboug
NE
```

which is better in your case and the way you search.

more info about it you can find here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm#i1006391

Good luck!

Comment: That seems like the answer! Your hypothesis is corroborated by the fact that searching for the column name usually yields all rows too. (I tried 'city', 'state', 'zip') IMHO - this is a bug since the result of the query should not depend on the data storage format. Thanks very much!